# How to escape $ and { } braces in sed expression

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace text `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` with user input in a variable `$TARGETDIR`

```
sudo sed -i -e 's|${APACHE_LOG_DIR}|$TARGETDIR|g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/$NAME.conf
```

Where TARGETDIR and NAME are user inputs.

Problem is that when using single quotes, the $TARGETDIR won't be parsed and put as it is. And when using double quotes, `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` is being considered an expression which is actually the text in the file I just want to be replaced.

I tried escaping in double-quotes like with forward slash like following:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s|\$\{APACHE_LOG_DIR\}|$TARGETDIR|g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/$NAME.conf
```

But then I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

What is correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using single and double quotes together? Like `'s|\$\{APACHE_LOG_DIR\}|'"$TARGETDIR"'|g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-E` and write the match string as a proper regex.
Try this for instance:

```
sed -i -e -E "s/[$][{]APACHE_LOG_DIR[}]/$TARGETDIR/g" $NAME.conf
```

Comment: Actually this worked `sed -i -e "s/[$][{]APACHE_LOG_DIR[}]/$TARGETDIR/g" $NAME.conf`